# Grails command object initialization

Tags: grails, data-binding

In my Grails 2.3.8 app, I've defined the following controller action

```
class RegisterController {

    def register(User user) {
        render text: "User name is '$user.name'"
    }
}
```

The `user` argument is a domain class instance. If I invoke this controller with the URL

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/register/register
```

I get a `NullPointerException`. However my understanding of databinding is that if this action is invoked without any parameters, the argument should be assigned a `new User()`

Comment: Nope. If there is no valid `id` present in the url, the user domain will be null.

Comment: @dmahapatro are you sure? If that's true, it seems you could never use an action parameter with an action that saves a new domain class instance

Comment: @dmahapatro I'm not sure that's true. If you pass just a single form parameter that matches any of the fields in the target object, Data binding will occur.

Comment: @Dónal I wonder if it's not behaving like a command object since this is a Domain class. Could you try it with just a command object and see if you get the same results? Sounds like a bug to me. I frequently use command objects with optional/no params for backing data in the model. That's why I think it's a bug.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore you're right, if I make it a command object, I don't get an exception. I guess this is a Grails bug, I've opened a JIRA ticket https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11393

Comment: @dmahapatro is kind of correct, but not entirely.  If no id is present and the request is a POST request, then a new instance is created.

Comment: @Dónal Sorry, got pulled over to a long meeting. The verbiage about POST request was added as part of 2.4.0 RC1 (as mentioned by Jeff) and not present in [v2.3.8](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects).Yes as far as v2.3.8 goes HTTP GET request will give you a null if there is no `id` present in the url param.

Comment: Oops. Wasn't aware of https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11247 too.

Comment: @rmlan Incorrect. You can try it in this scenario without a POST request.

Comment: @dmahapatro Yes. I realize now that OP was strictly talking about a GET

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However my understanding of databinding is that if this action is
>   invoked without any parameters, the argument should be assigned a new
>   User()

That is not necessarily the case.  For domain class command objects if no parameters are present a new instance is only created for POST requests.

From http://grails.org/doc/2.4.0.RC1/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects...

> If the command object's type is a domain class and there is no id
>   request parameter then null will be passed into the controller action
>   unless the HTTP request method is "POST", in which case a new instance
>   of the domain class will be created by invoking the domain class
>   constructor.

That text may be missing from the 2.3.8 docs.  I will verify that and add it if necessary.

Comment: I have verified that the notes have already been updated for 2.3.x (https://github.com/grails/grails-doc/commit/b019c1184cc8e8ed9638118f4f66a58527a1ea1c).  The web site will be updated to reflect that clarification the next time the docs are published, which will probably be in the next week or so with 2.3.9 is released.

Comment: Note that this behavior changed in 2.3.8 as https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11247 was addressed.

Comment: The reasoning behind GRAILS-11247 is not obvious to me, i.e. *why* is a new object created for a POST request when the command is a non-domain class, but not when the command *is* a domain class?

Comment: Regular command objects and domain classes are fundamentally different things.  Other command objects are a convenient way to bundle up and relate request params to simplify tedious controller code. Domain classes are persistent resources managed by the application. They aren't the same thing at all so the rules for how the framework interacts with them are different. There are good reasons that relate to REST practices (but are good ideas in general) that explain why domain classes are treated the way they are but this answers the question of why they are not handled the same as plain COs.

Comment: If you are doing things right, if domain classes were created for all requests, you would have to put tedious code in your controller action to figure out what happened. As it is now, the combination of URL mappings and allowedMethods eliminates lots of that.

Answer (score -2):

What if you modify:

```
'$user.name'
```

To be:

```
'${user?.name}'
```

Comment: Then I obviously won't get the NPE, but that's not really the point of my question